# SQL Server Column Encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, encryption

I have a couple of columns in my application that need to encrypted for security reasons.  How is this possible with SQL Server 2008?  Also, would I need to always manually decrypt them or will it happen automatically?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Certificate` and then a `Symmetric Key` that uses the certificate:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE YourCertificate
 WITH SUBJECT = 'Encrypted Content';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key
  WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
   ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE YourCertificate;
GO
```

To Decrypt: You can use `DecryptByKey`:

The example from MSDN is:

```
SELECT CardNumber, CardNumber_Encrypted AS 'Encrypted card number',
   CONVERT(nvarchar,
   DecryptByKey(CardNumber_Encrypted, 1 , 
   HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(varbinary, CreditCardID)))) AS 'Decrypted card number'  
FROM Sales.CreditCard;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: will i need to do any decryption in my code or will sql server handle that?

Comment: @SachinKainth - You will need to decrypt manually.  You can do that via DecryptByKey (See my edit)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look MSDN post [How to: Encrypt a Column of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First off: Create your assym Key using this code:

```
USE [yourDB]    
GO    
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ClaveAsym    
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 ---->Take a look in this type of algorithms    
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'yourKey'
GO
```

*Remember this, you must to declare a variable always that you want to decrypt or encrypt:*

```
DECLARE @KEYID INT SET @KEYID = AsymKey_ID('ClaveAsym')
```

**Decrypting data**

```
SELECT columnA, CAST(DecryptByAsymKey(@keyid, columnUser, N'yourKey') AS VARCHAR(100)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(@keyId, columnPass, N'yourKey')) FROM yourTable
```

**Encrypting Data**

```
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(MAX), @pass VARCHAR(MAX)    
SET @User = 'yourUser'    
sET @pass = 'yourPass'    
DECLARE @KEYID INT SET @KEYID = AsymKey_ID('ClaveAsym')    
INSERT INTO yourTable( User, passw) VALUES EncryptByAsymKey (@keyid, @User ), EncryptByAsymKey (@keyid, @pass))
```